# How to renew the enrollment using Hyperledger Fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

The enrollments of my Hyperledger Fabric peers and orderers will be expired soon. I'm running the Fabric CA server, so I try to renew the enrollments(as far as I know, MSP, not TLS), but I cannot find any document about it.

How can I renew my enrollments? Could you recommend any guide or document about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To renew the enrollment you can use the `fabric-ca-client reenroll` command. If you want to reuse the same key which was used during the enrollment then you can use the `--csr.keyrequest.reusekey` flag.

More information on the command usage can be found [here](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/clientcli.html#fabric-ca-client-s-cli)

I am also kind of stuck on this thing! This is what i have gathered so far, I would really appreciate it if you could let me know if you get it working.

Comment: Check the answers in my another question. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67072278/tls-certificate-renewal-deadlock-among-raft-orderers-after-expiry

@yacovm gave me great guides to renew my TLS and MSP keys.

Comment: I checked that question, and the JIRA which was mentioned by @yavcom. What i take after going through that discussion is that the channel configuration needs to be updated with the new msp/tls certificates. but what if there's no new msp/tls are generated and are reenrolled as i have mentioned in my answer above? Could you please have a look at my questions here and guide me whether my understanding is correct or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565452/hyperledger-fabric-how-to-manage-the-enrollment-and-certificates-expiry