# TLS certificate renewal deadlock among RAFT orderers after expiry

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

TLS and MSP certificates of Orderers and Peers in my network were expired. So, I renewed them and change TLS, MSP folder to new one. After restart all my Orderers and Peers, Orderers keep `SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE: rejected by Consenter: channel identitych is not serviced by me` error from all orderers. Querying the chaincode to each peer works well, so it seems like an orderer's problem.

When my orderer started, the orderer logged a warning like below:

```
[orderer.consensus.etcdraft] detectSelfID -> WARN 015 Could not find -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIC8DCCApagAwIBAgIUOhF5HhLQW...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 among [-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIC5TCCAougAwIBAgIUApCtD3xfo9JLFyPd...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIC5DCCAougAwIBAgIUQ/ztvrcb3Z6LB8...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIC5DCCAougAwIBAgIUSCeIphcSIWrs...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
]
```

The location of this warning and `channel ... is not serviced by me` error are same, so I guess these are same problem.

The problem looks like that my new TLS signed certificate is not recognized from blocks' meta information.

Thanks for some comments from the community, I found below link and it seems very close to my problem.

https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-16953

However, even I set TLSHandshakeTimeShift to 20s and restart orderers one by one, still the problem occurs. My environment setting is like below:

```
docker container run -d --name $NODE \
--log-driver json-file --log-opt max-size=1g --log-opt max-file=1 \
-e FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0 \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/artifacts/genesis.block \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=$MSP \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/artifacts/msp \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/artifacts/tls/keystore/key.pem \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/artifacts/tls/signcerts/cert.pem \
-e "ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/artifacts/tls/tlscacerts/ca-cert.pem]" \
-e ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1 \
-e ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/artifacts/tls/keystore/key.pem \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/artifacts/tls/signcerts/cert.pem \
-e "ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/artifacts/tls/tlscacerts/ca-cert.pem]" \
-e ORDERER_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=$NODE:8443 \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_TLSHANDSHAKETIMESHIFT=48h \
-w="/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric" \
-v "$(pwd)"/artifacts:/artifacts \
-v "$(pwd)"/blocks:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/ \
--network $NETWORK \
hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$VERSION orderer
```

Did I do some wrong to set TLSHANDSHAKETIMESHIFT value? Still I could not find any solution for my problem. Any kind of helps are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: why do you set it to 20s ? it's 20 seconds. You need to set it to a bigger time, like 24h or 48h , etc. depends on when your certificates expired.  Look at https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-18384 it has more discussions.

Comment: @yacovm I change TLSHandshakeTimeShift value to 48h and restart all orderers. However, the same problem did not disappear.

Comment: did you use the previous, expired certificates? when did they expire?

Comment: @yacovm Okay, now I read the link you attached. In my case, I already update renewed MSP and TLS certs. But, according to the link, I need to use old certs (MSP, TLS) and set TLSHandshake, and then update config one by one. Is it correct?

Comment: yes, exactly, you need to use the previous  certificates in the local folders of the MSP and TLS

Comment: So, let me summarize the process. Orderers are with old TLS/MSP certs, and TLSHandshake, NoExpirationCheck set, and peers are with old TLS/MSP set. Then, I need to send channel config update with new TLS/MSP cert via a peer to the target orderer one by one. After updating channel config, update local folders of MSP, TLS of the target orderer to new one. After finishing on all orderers, update all MSP/TLS of peers at once. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. That's how you do it.

Comment: Thanks! Now I got the point. Then, is the link below a correct way to update a channel config for this case?
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/config_update.html#

Comment: Yes, you can also take a look at my script here https://github.com/SmartBFT-Go/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4-BFT/first-network/scripts/bftutil.sh just don't use the ecert variable since in Raft there is no ecert, only TLS.