# Hyperledger Fabric: How to manage the enrollment and certificates expiry?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

To simulate the MSP and certificate expiry of nodes [orderer & peer], I updated the expiry time to 1h (the default is 8760h which is 1 year in hours) in the `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` file. I am not sure, if this is the correct way to do it?

Please feel free to correct me

Hyperledger Fabric v2.3 and Fabric CA v.1.5.0

**fabric-ca-server-config.yaml**: Org1 - the Org1 Fabric CA server is using this config

```
signing:
default:
  usage:
    - digital signature
  expiry: 1h
profiles:
  ca:
     usage:
       - cert sign
       - crl sign
     expiry: 43800h
     caconstraint:
       isca: true
       maxpathlen: 0
  tls:
     usage:
        - signing
        - key encipherment
        - server auth
        - client auth
        - key agreement
     expiry: 1h
```

Right before the expiry time, I successfully (did not get any error) reenrolled the MSP and TLS certs of all using the **fabric-ca-client reenroll** command along with **--csr.keyrequest.reusekey**. More info on the command usage can be found [here](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/clientcli.html#fabric-ca-client-s-cli)

I checked the logs in all the nodes and the peer nodes were spitting logs as:

```
2021-07-27 13:51:11.747 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 0e9 Server TLS handshake failed in 1.807206ms with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.26.0.9:49338
```

Also, I was not able to transact on the network, which is obvious because of the above error. I believe this affects the MSP and TLS certs generated for the organization admin and user as well.

1. Could anyone be kind enough to shed some lights on the
   fabric-ca-server-config.yaml and how to reenroll or re-issue the
   certificates so the fabric-network can function normally?
2. After the certificates are expired already, the reenroll command is giving error - not a valid certificate. The certificate which is referred in the **--tls.certfiles**  flag is the root CA tls certificate. The root tls certificate of the CA should not expire??

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72387688/tls-expired-hyperledger-fabric-orderers-cannot-be-launched-even-with-tlshandshak/77008751#77008751